# Can Service Workers receive pushes when not installed on mobile?

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I think I know the answer to this question from my experiments, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer when doing research.

Is is possible to send notifications to a PWA when it is opened in Chrome on mobile, but isn't installed?

Once it is installed I can receive notifications, but I can't before.

I'm having a hard time getting remote debugging working for my mobile so it's difficult to tell if the push event is even firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they can.

The problem was that I had notifications enabled for my site, but disabled for Chrome itself.

Comment: It is always that small hidden mistake XD

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications), don't specify the need to install the pwa to be able to use the notification feature. However what I suspect is happening in your case is that Chrome is not giving priority to notify to the notification that you are sending without installing. What I mean is that you might receive your notification on the regular wakeup cycle of Chrome, and not as a background task. (But this is just a speculation)

Another common scenario that happens a lot, trust me :-), is that you forgot to give permission to send notifications in the first place.

Regarding remote debugging, refer the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging), to get it setup on Android. As a lot of the online tutorials are a bit out of date.

Note: I found an article online that shows a notification received without installing on Android, here is its [link](https://www.codemag.com/article/1901031/Implementing-Push-Notifications-in-Progressive-Web-Apps-PWAs-Using-Firebase), it might not be very helpful for your case but check it out you might figure something out.

Comment: thanks, do you know where I can find more information about priority? I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere.

I've been very careful about permissions so they're definitely allowed.

Yeah I was following that remote debugging tutorial, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Oh no, the fact that it's possible means I'm not going to be able to let this go!

Comment: Searching on the internet I couldn't find something about the priority, that's why I said it is a speculation, but I assumed it since Chrome will try to limit the power usage of the app, hence why I think they might implement such a system, where noninstalled pwa become completely dormant when the site is not active because if you think about it, a lot of the websites nowadays have a service worker implemented in them, think about all of the websites that you opened once, staying active on your phone when chrome is closed will definitely cause a  high power consumption. But I can't confirm it.

Comment: Most welcome, glad I was able to help :-)